# Entity Framework C# Introducing A Foreign Key X In Table Y May Cause Cycles OR Multiple Cascade Paths

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am developing a C# MVC application. I am using Code First approach to model my database.

My project had the following requirements:

1. Company Can Have Many Products
2. Product Can have many Advertisement
   Types

Here are model classes (code first solution) to the above mentioned problem.

```
    public class Company
    {

        public Company()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Logo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Company Description")]
        public string CompanyDescription { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Employees { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
       public int ProductID { get; set; }

       public DateTime Created { get; set; }

       public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

       public string ProductName { get; set; }

       public int CompanyID { get; set; }

       public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<AdvertisementType> AdvertisementTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdvertisementType
    {
       public int AdvertisementTypeID { get; set; }

       public int ProductID { get; set; }

       [Display(Name = "Advertisement Name")]
       public string AdvertisementTypeName { get; set; }

       public DateTime Created { get; set; }

       public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

       public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to update the database, after creating the migrations i get the following error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.AdvertisementTypes_dbo.Products_ProductID' on table 'AdvertisementTypes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I have been trying solve this problem but unable to find any solution. I don't find any problem with the model classes, nor i think there are any issues with the relationship between the models.

Any suggestions or help will be useful.

**EDIT**

Here is screenshot of Tables and their relations

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your dbContext you need to turn cascade delete to false if you want to avoid that.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

{

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

}
```

You can initialize your  make a List() in Product like you did with Company class...

```
public class Product
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }

public Product()
    {
        this.AdvertisementTypes = new List<AdvertisementType>();
    }
```

Comment: But i want to make advertisement type belong to a product